# TAB problema con la hoja de estilos CSS

Tags: html, css

Tengo un problema con el `HTML` y la hoja de estilos en una navegación con pestañas.

Cuando paso el puntero del ratón sobre la pestaña, esta no funciona correctamente, *solo en los extremos de la pestaña*; si doy clic en el medio de la pestaña, no hace nada para cambiar de pestaña.

Son 3 pestañas que al dar clic en cada una, cambia de pestaña y muestra un nueva vista.

He intentado:

- Cambiar la propiedad `display: table-cell;` a otra cosa: funciona pero no quedan las pestañas una al lado de la otra que es lo que quiero.
- cambiando a `float` de la etiqueta `a` y con la propiedad  `display: inline-block;` pero continúa con el mismo problema, solo funciona bien la primera pues en la primera pestaña puedo dar clic en cualquier lado de la pestaña.

En la 2 y 3 solo en los extremos de la pestaña, si hago click en el medio de ella no hace nada y no aparece la manito del `pointer`.

Este es mi código:

```css
.wn_services-tabs {
        .wn_fl;
        display: table;
        border-bottom: 0;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        a {
            display: table-cell;
            background: @services-tabs-background;
            line-height: 58px;
            color: black;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            .wn_font-medium();
            color: @services-tabs-color;
            font-size: 1.4em;
            text-decoration: none;
            border: 1px solid @services-outer-border;
            position: relative;
            width: 186px;
            text-align: center;
            border-bottom: 0;
            outline: 0;
            background-clip: padding-box;
            padding: 0;
            &:hover {
                background-color: white;
            }
            .wn_ico {
                display: inline-block;
                width: 14px;
                height: 14px;
                border-radius: 20px;
                vertical-align: middle;
                margin-right: 4px;
            }
            &.wn_active {
                background-color: white;
                z-index: 10;
                &:before {
                    content: "";
                    height: 3px;
                    width: 100%;
                    left: 0;
                    top: -3px;
                    background: @services-tabs-active-border;
                    position: absolute;
                }
            }   
        }
```

```html
<div class="wn_services-tabs">
 <a href="#" ng-repeat="tab in statusCtrl.tabs" ng-class="{wn_active:statusCtrl.isActiveTab(tab.key)}" ng-click="statusCtrl.onClickTab($event, tab.key)">aaa</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu código no es probable porque utilizas angular para generar las tabs. De todos modos, te pongo un ejemplo sencillo con Flexbox.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}
.tab {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .5rem .8rem;
}
.tab:not(:first-of-type) {
  border-left: none;
}
.tab:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="tab">Tab 1</a>
<a href="" class="tab">Tab 2</a>
<a href="" class="tab">Tab 3</a>
```